# How was the date of December 4, 292,277,026,596 calculated for the overflow of the 64 bit signed unix timestamp?

Tags: python, computer-science, unix-timestamp

I've tried to calculate the date myself using the maximum 64-bit signed integer but always end up with another date that's a few million years different. I've tried using sidereal years and leap years but I always get results that are at least a few million years off.

Here is what I've tried thus far:

`dateA = 1970 + (9223372036854775807/31556926.08)`

`dateB = 1970 + (9223372036854775807/31536000) + (((9223372036854775807/31536000)/4)/365)`

Both return the wrong answer. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure the signed value is used as the limit? Some implementations use unsigned one.

Comment: Did you even google how to calculate leap year? - you're missing multiple parts that could affect things out that long.

Comment: But even if the leap year was wrong wouldn't the sidereal year be correct?

Comment: It also appears that even google's conversions have this wrong as it returns a date a few billion years off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to account for the years that are leap years. A year is a leap year if:

- it is evenly divisible by 4;
- *unless* it is evenly divisible by 100;
- *or* if it's evenly divisible by 400.

As a rough estimate for the year, calculating `1970 + 0x7fffffffffffffff // 86400 // (365 + 1/4 - 1/100 + 1/400)` gives an answer of 292277026596. I'll leave the derivation of the exact day as an exercise for the reader.

I used Python 3 for this calculation which gives real results for integer divides. Adjust accordingly for Python 2.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't import division from `__future__`, so that was screwing up all my results, now it's accurate to the day.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `datetime` to do some of the heavy lifting.

```
>>> import datetime
```

First, the Gregorian calendar repeats exactly every 400 years.  Here's the number of days in a 400-year cycle:

```
>>> 365 * 400 + 100 - 4 + 1
146097
```

Clear?  Every year has at least 365 days.  There would be 100 leap years (+100), except years divisible by 100 aren't leap years (-4), except years divisible by 400 are leap years (+1).

Then use that to figure out how many 400-year blocks fit in a number of seconds equal to the largest 63-bit integer:

```
>>> divmod((1 << 63) - 1, 146097 * 24 * 3600)
(730692561, 7161147007)
```

So we have 730692561 400-year blocks, with 7161147007 seconds left over.  `datetime` can directly compute that number of seconds beyond the epoch:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=7161147007)
datetime.datetime(2196, 12, 4, 15, 30, 7)
```

So, except for the year, the last representable second is on December 4th at 15:30:07 UTC.

To get the year, just add the 730692561 400-year blocks:

```
>>> 2196 + 730692561 * 400
292277026596
```

Comment: Subtracting exact multiples of 400 years is brilliant, I wish I'd thought of it.

Comment: Heh - I wrote the `datetime` module, and it does something very similar internally, just in case we someday allowed unbounded ints for the years ;-)

Comment: I saw this answer again and it occurred to me that in 400 years you might end up on a different day of the week, so I checked: 146097 % 7 == 0. Those Gregorians thought of everything!

Comment: Yes, I didn't define "repeats exactly" because it encompasses subtleties, but "retains the weekday" is one of them.  An easy visualization:  if you're given a sequence of 400 consecutive yearly calendars without year markers, it's impossible to determine what the years are, but you can determine the starting year mod 400.

Comment: BTW, that the number of days in the 400-year leap-year pattern is divisible by the 7 days in the weekday pattern appears to be a lucky coincidence.  I don't think it was designed that way.  The funky Gregorian leap-year rules were a refinement of the simpler Julian rules, and the 4-year leap-year pattern in the latter did not comprise a whole number of weeks.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's a coincidence too. My previous comment was meant to be both informative and humorous. Now if the rules for *Easter* repeat every 400 years, then I'd truly be amazed...